# What happens when you cool down a now closed container after the water evaporated in a open contained beforehand?

Tags: pressure, gas, molecules

Imagine you heat up water in an open container until enough water vapor diffuses in the air. Then you stop heating the container, close the lid, and you cool it down. What happens next? This is my first time posting on this website so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question or if I am doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: take an empty water bottle. Close the lid tightly and place in fridge. Look a few hours later…

Comment: Re, "until enough water vapor diffuses..." Enough for what? How "open" is the container? Niels Nielsen's answer describes what will happen if the opening is small enough, and you close the container quickly enough so that there is no gas in the container when you close it except for steam (i.e., H2O gas.) The longer you wait before closing it however, the more air will be able to enter. Likewise, the larger the opening, the less time you will have before a significant amount of air enters.

Comment: Mandatory Mythbusters  video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kM-k1zofs58

Answer (score 1):

The vapor blows the air out of the top of the container, displacing it with water vapor. When you close it up and let it cool down, the vapor condenses and a vacuum develops inside the container. The ambient atmospheric pressure outside the container is no longer balanced by the lower pressure inside the container, and the container gets squeezed by the pressure difference. If the container is made out of thin metal, the atmospheric pressure will collapse and crush the container.

Answer (score 0):

According to Temperature-Vapor pressure curve, internal pressure of the container keeps going down to the specific value as shown in the curve.

To be brief, a vacuum condition would occur at the work you mentioned!